# Intercept and modify traffic to and from tomcat

Tags: testing, tomcat, networking

I have an application deployed on tomcat on my localhost. I want to intercept and modify the requests that the application makes and the responses that it receives. Is there a tool to do this? I have tried out **Burp** but i've only been able to intercept traffic to and from Firefox browser using it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the [OWASP Zed Attack Proxy](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project).

It will be able to intercept any request from a browser than supports proxies (Firefox, IE, Chrome, Opera...)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about [Servlet Filters](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html) that intercept the requests and responses to servlets (and are placed in a FilterChain).

Comment: I don't want to do it in code. The application is already deployed in tomcat. I want to modify its requests and responses from an external tool. That's why I asked whether there was a tool that did this.

Answer (score 0):

As `Vikdor` said [Servlet Filters](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html) should do the trick. You need to modify the web.xml of each application running on the tomcat, and write your filter code in java as a Filter.

If you want to do a simple task, like redirect an url or add a header you can use [UrlRewriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/), for a more complex/custom task you should write your own code.

Comment: I don't want to do it in code. The application is already deployed in tomcat. I want to modify its requests and responses from an external tool. That's why I asked whether there was a tool that did this.

Comment: With UrlRewriteFilter you don't need to write code, just put the jar in the lib directory and customize a xml. You can also put another application like apache httpd, but the rules you'll have to use are similar to the rules you can write with UrlRewriteFilter.